# React Portal Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a problem to render an input field with an portal.
When I change a the value of the input, it looses focus.
I think it´s because of rerendering on state change.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zk0w1jv6rp

Does anybody know a solution?

**UPDATE**

Is there a way that the Bar-Componet will be reused? Lets say I could add something like a key property, so that react knows that it´s the same component and can reuse it.

Comment: You are changing the state so react renders the input. There is no wonder. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Fill out the inputfield like a normal user. Best would be to reuse the input field... and not rerender the whole component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because each time `HelloReact` component re-render, you are defining a new `Bar` component and creating a new Bar component, that is not a good approach.

Simple solution is use `autoFocus`, so each time when it create a new `Bar` component, it will focus the input element.

[Working code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/62830zpvxk)

Better way would be to define `Bar` component outside of `HelloReact` component and pass the `value` and `onChange` event handler in props. In that case you don't need to use `autoFocus`.

[Example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0lknppv)

Comment: both of your links are non-working examples...
When I would use the "Better way", the amount of properties would be huge. The example I provided is a cleaned up example.

Comment: Best would be if I could put a key propertie to the Bar-Component so that React knows "hey it's the same I don´t have to make a full rerender for this portal"

Comment: Not good with codesandbox, updated the first link please check. 2nd one (Example) is working for me, can you tell me what exactly is failing?

Comment: Well I reafactored that part of my application to a seperated component, but I hope, that sometimes there will be away that the portalized component can be reused, when the parent is rerendered.